# Resampling a signal with variable frequency

Tags: python, time-frequency, time-series, time-domain

I haven't touched my signal processing courses for a long time and I forget how to work with these kinds of signals.

I have a signal that comes from a sensor that has 3 time periods.
The time vector of my signal is described by something like this:

\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{align}
&t\\
&t+T_0\\
&t + T_0 + T_1\\
&t + T_0 + T_1 + T_2\\
&t + 2 \cdot T_0 + T_1 + T_2\\
&t + 2 \cdot T_0 + 2 \cdot T_1 + T_2\\
&t + 2 \cdot T_0 + 2 \cdot T_1 + 2 \cdot T_2\\
&\vdots\\
&t + k \cdot T_0 + T_1 + T_2\\
&t + k \cdot T_0 + k \cdot T_1 + T_2\\
&t + k \cdot T_0 + k \cdot T_1 + k \cdot T_2
\end{align}
\end{bmatrix}

With $ T_1 = 2 \cdot T_0 $ and $ T_2 = 3 \cdot T_0 $

I want to do some signal processing and implement an algorithm, but I need a constant time period in my signal to do so.
I was wondering if there is a way to resample my signal ?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  I've closed your question as a duplicate as there are a few questions with answers already on the site that attempt to deal with your question.  Please review the one I've marked as duplicate (and its answers) and let us know if that helps.  If it doesn't help, please [edit your question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/85281/edit) to update it with what extra help is needed.  Ping me once that's done and I can reopen the question for answers.

Comment: No worries, thank you for directing me to the right topic.
By the way I tried to do something but I don't know if it is a good idea:
I have my time vector, I took the min and max and recreated a new time vector of the same size but with a constante time period and I used the `signal.resample` function of `scipy` using Python, it seems to be working for my case but I cannot explain it.

Comment: That's what I'd try first, keep it simple.  If it doesn't work, then express what doesn't work for you and let's try to answer **that** question.